# Is there any difference between filtering and sanitizing input? Are they, along with parameterized instructions, efficient against SQLi and XSS?

Tags: php, security

I'm trying to understand about how to mitigate some security threats (SQLi, XSS and so on). However, I'm confused about the `filter_input()` and `filter_var()` functions.

**What I understand about these functions is:**

The `filter_input()` function filters the user input, that is, if the user enters some SQL statement command, then this command will not be executed, it will be understood as any string, not as a command. So that's your role.

The `filter_var()` function aims to validate if a certain variable matches the filter type, that is, if it uses `filter_var('bob@mail.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`, so if the user provides an input that does not match the filter, a boolean value will be returned: *false*. And then, it's up to the developer to decide what to do in this situation. So, I believe that this function only validates an input following a specific filter, it does not clean the input.

So I'd like to know if I'm right about what I know about these two functions. It's a little confusing to me, the two look similar.

Also, if I'm correct about my line of reasoning, would these two functions, along with parameterized instructions, be effective in mitigating more common threats in web applications? Maybe SQLi and XSS?

I say *effective* because *it's not enough*. Web application security doesn't just demand that. However, I believe you understand what I mean by this.

Comment: Yes, filtering is getting the subset of the whole that you are interested in, Sanitising is making sure the data contains no nasties.